Webpack Encore : share the env files between Symfony and React
This happens in a particular context, I don't recommend it, but I deal with it, and maybe if you fall here, you too.
I have a React app wrapped into Symfony with Webpack Encore. This issue can be extended to other javascript frameworks.
I've been looking for a way to use my env variables in React as well as in Symfony.
I use the basic .env as a .env.sample but with default values. I have .env.local, .env.{env_type} and even .env.{env_type}.local to fit my environment. In addition, they are not mandatory, developers can create or not these env files.
I also need to keep most of my variables private, so out of React but only on Symfony.

To do that, I have applied the following updates into webpack.config.js.
By convention, I used the "REACT_APP_" pattern to differentiate between variables accessible from the front and private ones.
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const fs = require('fs');

// ...

Encore.
    // ...
    .configureDefinePlugin(options => {
        const env = dotenv.config({ path: getEnvPaths() });

        if (env.error) {
            throw env.error;
        }

        Object.entries(env.parsed).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            if (key.startsWith('REACT_APP_')) {
                options['process.env.' + key] = JSON.stringify(value);
            }
        });
    })
    //...
    ;

function getEnvPaths() {
    let envmode = '';
    switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
        case 'production':
            envmode = 'prod';
            break;
        case 'test':
            envmode = 'test';
            break;
        // case 'development':
        default:
            envmode = 'dev';
    }
    return [`.env.${envmode}.local`, '.env.local', `.env.${envmode}`, '.env'].filter(
        fileExists
    );
}

function fileExists(filePath) {
    try {
        return fs.statSync(filePath).isFile();
    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
}

JSON.stringify() is surprisingly important, because otherwise the process.env.VALUES is considered as a variable name and not a value.
